# MAUI Project Works on Android But Crashes on IOS

Tags: maui

I have a project using RC1 of MAUI that is running fine on the Android emulator.  When it runs on an emulated iOS device, it always crashes.  The code in question is based in the constructor for a form.  I need some code I need to run async (which you can't do in a constructor), so my code kicks it off like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => 
{ 
    AppCheck(); 
});
```

All the code is doing right now is creating a globally scoped variable's property, then setting the binding context, like this:

```
BindingContext = App.Status;
```

I get a dialog on the Mac where the emulator is running that says it "quit unexpectedly" with a bunch of crash dump details.  On the Android emulator, it all just works.  So looking for suggestions on what to do here, i.e. is there someplace I can or should upload the dump file, or does iOS just not deal with async code, or ??

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: to start, add some exception handling to your code to try and catch the exception causing the crash.  You can also try using a crash reporting tool like appcenter.ms

Comment: Your code does two things, and you don’t know which causes the crash. Comment out the second one (Bindingcontext..). Still crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**VERSION 1**

It might be safer to set BindingContext on Dispatcher’s thread (MainThread):

```
Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
    BindingContext = ..
);
```

---

**VERSION 2**

If you want to use `await` on Main thread:

```
Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
{
    await ...;
    BindingContext = ...
});
```

---

**VERSION 3**

If you have async code that you'd rather run on background thread:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    // On background thread.
    await ...;
    ...
    Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
    {
        // On Main thread.
        BindingContext = ..
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, you were both right, thanks for the suggestions.  So in a nutshell, after throwing everything in a try block, I see the exception is when I set the BindingContext.  By changing it to happen on the Dispatcher's thread as suggested above, it doesn't blow up.  For completeness, here's the exception it was throwing when it was set in an async method: {UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.
   at UIKit.UIApplication.EnsureUIThread()
   at UIKit.UILabel.set_Text(String value)

Comment: Added alternatives that might be useful.